# SparkSession does not pull down packages from repo in pytest suite

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, pytest

I have a pytest suite. In the pytest suite, I have a majority of tests that **do not** need additional packages pulled down from maven via `"spark.jars.packages"`, and 2 tests that **do**.

My thought was for the 2 tests that do, I will:

1. Stop the existing SparkSession used for the tests that do not require additional packages with `spark.stop()` using pytest `tearDown()`.
2. Create an new SparkSession that has `"spark.jars.packages"` and `"spark.jars.repositories"` specified to download the additional required packages using pytest `setUp()`.

This is not working as expected, and the new SparkSession that has `"spark.jars.packages"` and `"spark.jars.repositories"` does not download the additional packages.

To my surprise, the pytest suite will only pass if I run the tests that require a `SparkSession` **with** `"spark.jars.packages"` and `"spark.jars.repositories"` **first** in the test suite. If I run it second, I get a `package not found error`, and the required packages were clearly not pulled down from their repo.

My initial assumption was that on the second run, pyspark was referencing the initial `SparkSession` without `"spark.jars.packages"` and `"spark.jars.repositories"`. However, what I have confirmed is:

1. At the point where the first `SparkSession` is stopped, and the second will be created, a `SparkSession` does not exist.
2. At the point where the first `SparkContext` is stopped, and the second will be created, a `SparkContext` does not exist.
3. When the second `SparkSession` is created, `"spark.jars.packages"` and `"spark.jars.repositories"` are correctly registered in the Spark Configuration.

What am I missing here? I dug through the pyspark source code to check why this is the case and could not figure it out. Thanks so much.

**Example code showing the problem:**

(I am inspecting the error to make the example runnable without the need to really access s3. If everything is setup correctly I expect `AccessDeniedException` which is fine. The problem I get raises `ClassNotFoundException` because `spark.jars.packages` do not get fetched)

```
from py4j.protocol import Py4JJavaError
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession


def spark_session_default():
    return SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()


def spark_session_s3_config():
    spark_builder = (
        SparkSession.builder
        # install dependencies to work with AWS S3 eg. org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem class
        .config("spark.jars.packages", "org.apache.spark:spark-hadoop-cloud_2.12:3.3.0")
    )
    return spark_builder.getOrCreate()


def try_write_s3_file(spark: SparkSession):
    try:
        spark.createDataFrame(data=[(1, 2, 3)], schema=["a", "b", "c"]).write.csv("s3a://mybucket/dataset1")
    except Py4JJavaError as e:
        assert \
            e.java_exception.getClass().getName() == "java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException", \
            f"Expected AccessDeniedException but got {e.java_exception.getMessage()}"
        print("Successfully tried writing to S3! (got Access Denied and not ClassNotFoundException)")


# Comment out 2 lines below to make the example run fine
spark = spark_session_default()  
spark.stop() 
try_write_s3_file(spark_session_s3_config())
```

Comment: in unit test envioronment generally org wont allow to download jar packages . you can supply them in lib folder under test and point your code there ...  so that for unit test case envt it will be available

Comment: I am getting the same problem - did you find a solution to "force" spark to install the packages?

Answer (score 2):

I have found open issue in Spark's JIRA which mentions a solution (quite hacky) https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-38438

To properly close the Spark session you have to also stop the underlying JVM:

```
s.stop()
s._sc._gateway.shutdown()
s._sc._gateway.proc.stdin.close()
SparkContext._gateway = None
SparkContext._jvm = None
```

I tested it with the example code and it worked - the `spark.jars.packages` got installed if the previous session got stopped "properly".